# Resolve all Services matching an intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, intentfilter, android-package-managers

I want to retrieve all services matching a specific intent-filter. I have the following code :

AndroidManifest.xml of a TestService :

```
    <service
        android:name=".TestService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.example.MY_PERMISSIONS"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.myaction" />

            <data
                android:host="myhost"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Querying the PackageManager in the application :

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.myaction");
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, 0);
    Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(resolveInfos.size()));
```

This returns a value = 0. I do not know what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Intent` does not match the `<intent-filter>`.

That is mostly a problem with the `<intent-filter>`, IMHO, as `<data>` and `<category>` are not usually used with service `<intent-filter>` definitions.

That being said, if you want to keep the `<intent-filter>` as-is, you need to have an `Intent` that matches the `<data>` and `<category>` as well as the `<action>`. Note that `Intents` used with services do *not* automatically get `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` added to them, the way `Intents` are when used with activities.

Comment: Thank you! removing `<data>` worked. How can i modify the intent to incorporate `<data>` with only only host and schema parameters as in my example?

Comment: @devashishjasani: Call `setData()` or `setDataAndType()` on the `Intent` with a suitable `Uri`.

Comment: Starting from Android 11. You further need: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility